# React Update Feedback Star Colour On Hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Playing around with a react component I found [here](https://github.com/voronianski/react-star-rating-component).

I'm trying to change the colour of the star when my mouse hovers over it without changing the colour when its active. So far the way I have done it, it changes all the star colours when I hover over 1 star. Would it be possible to change only the star the mouse is over? The set up I have is I set the empty star colour to white by default then update it via the star_over() function.

```
constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
          rating: 0,
          empty: '#fff'
        };
    }

    onStarClick(nextValue, prevValue, name) {
        this.setState({rating: nextValue});
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log("Sub")
    }

    star_over() {
        this.setState({empty: '#2C81B7'});
    }

    star_out() {
        this.setState({empty: '#fff'});
    }
```

Component:

```
<StarRatingComponent 
    name="rate1" 
    starCount={5}
    value={rating}
    onStarClick={this.onStarClick.bind(this)}
    onStarHover={this.star_over.bind(this)}
    onStarHoverOut={this.star_out.bind(this)}
    starColor={"Green"}
    emptyStarColor={empty}
    renderStarIcon={() => <Star className={classes.feedbackStar} />}
/>
```

**Update**

Tried doing it with CSS by adding a hover but doesn't highlight the empty stars as seen in the image below. Would need the 4th star highlighted too and the first 3 to remain green. Then if you highlighted the second star the third star would be empty.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you need a strictly react solution? if not, it's pretty simple to overwrite the css..

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do it in the setState. The documentation for the React component isn't the best. If there's a better way then I'm all ears :)

Comment: @djolf I've tried doing it using css and updated the question

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRwjjw deme. I think it's helpful for you.

Comment: @SujalPatel Thank's I'll check this out